# Does .NET have a case-ignoring implementation of IComparer<string>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, .net-core, icomparer

I have `Dictionary<string, int>`. I want to get my int value by string key, but ignore string case.

I just figured out, that I can use `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` constructor with `IComparer` parameter and `Dictionary` will use it to compare keys.

**But do I have to write `IComparer<string>` implementation myself?**

Comment: You mean  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ? "There is also a static String.Compare(String, String, StringComparison) method that performs a case-insensitive ordinal comparison if you specify a value of StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase for the StringComparison argument."

Comment: How are you using the dictionary and the comparer? Do you have some code you can show us?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [`StringComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=netcore-3.1) class provides a bunch of convenient `StringComparer` instances (which implement `IComparer<string>`) that does case-insensitive comparison:

- `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`
- `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`
- `OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Without knowing any more of your use case, I can't tell you *which* comparer you want to use. You need to think about which culture (or the invariant culture) you want the comparison to be in, or whether you want a simple ordinal comparison.

---

That said, `Dictionary` doesn't accept an `IComparer`, but an `IEqualityComparer`... But you can still use `StringComparer` nonetheless, it also implements `IEqualityComparer`.